# How to add column headers to file being output in R?

Tags: r, write.table

I am using the following code to create a neatly formatted output file with cleanly aligned columns:

```
library(gdata)
CompositeMatrix = cbind(array1,array2,array3)
    
write.fwf(CompositeMatrix,file="output.txt",sep="\t", quote=F,rownames=F,colnames=F)
```

However, the issue I have is that I haven't been able to add column headers to this file. If I change `colnames` to T, it just adds "V1", "V2", "V3" as the column headers. The `rowCol` argument of the `write.fwf()` function supposedly only works when rownames=T, and I don't want the row numbers shown. And, so far, specifying values for `rowCol` hasn't worked. Using `write.table()` isn't useful because the output file has staggered columns, which makes visual analysis of the outputs difficult.

Any suggestions about how I might modify the above code to add my column headers will be appreciated. Thanks!

Updates: (a) Gregor's suggestion worked to add the column headers to my output file -- thanks! (b) No, there are no column names in my matrix.

Comment: Are there column names in your matrix?

Comment: As a side note, it is better to write out TRUE and FALSE rather than using the shortcuts T and F. For example, R is fine with `F <- TRUE`, which will wreck your `write.fwf` line.

Comment: `colnames(CompositeMatrix) <- c("Column_1_name", "col2Name", "etc.")`. Then `colnames = T` in the write command.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no `write.fwf` function in R.

Comment: write.fwf is in package gdata

Answer (score 0):

With credits to @GregorThomas and the others: if the matrix does not have any column names we need to add them with `colnames()` before we use `write.fwf()`

```
library(gdata)
CompositeMatrix = cbind(array1, array2, array3)
colnames(CompositeMatrix) <- c("Col1Name", "Col2Name", "etc.")

write.fwf(CompositeMatrix, file="output.txt", sep="\t", quote=FALSE, rownames=FALSE, colnames=TRUE)
```